# How to bundle the v7-appcompat support library into an application source code?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

I'm writing an application which makes intensive use of the `v7-appcompat` support library on Android. At the beginning, I'd added the `.jar` file into the `libs` folder of my project, but that wasn't enough. Following the documentation (http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html), I've added another project in Eclipse with the support library and I've set this project as a dependency for my app.

It works.

By now I've my code on Github, but because of this, the code on Github doesn't even compile "out of the box", cause it misses the dependency.

Is there any way to bundle the support library directly into the source tree so that everyone can fork the project, add it to eclipse and run it immediately bypassing the process of creating the library project as dependency?

I've many other `.jar` files into the `libs` folder and I would love to do the same with the support library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to bundle the support library directly into the source tree so that everyone can fork the project, add it to eclipse and run it immediately bypassing the process of creating the library project as dependency?

Not very well. Moreover, it would be an exceedingly bad idea, unless you are planning on maintaining your own fork of `appcompat-v7` and having developers use your fork instead of the real one.

When you eventually switch over to Gradle-based builds, you can have the `appcompat-v7` repository artifact as a dependency. Then, people using your `build.gradle` file to build the project will download the artifact as needed to satisfy the dependency.

> I've many other .jar files into the libs folder

Those too really should be artifact dependencies. Admittedly, that's not readily possible with Ant or Eclipse builds. Maven and Gradle support this today, and Gradle is Google's long-term direction for project builds.

Answer (score 0):

Support library is probably an Android library in the sense that it contains resources, assets, and has an own AndroidManifest.xml.

What happens f you merge the resources, assets, and Manifest entries of the Support Library with your project?